# copy workbook (Template) multiple times and save into a specific folder with the copies saved as names based on a list in another workbook

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am tiring write VBA that runs from a button in a worksheet.

1/when the button is clicked, I was hoping the VBA in module1 of the workbook ("Testing Samples") would perform the bellow tasks

1/ Copy the workbook named ("Template") multiple times
2/ have those copied "Templates" saved into a specific folder named "To be completed".
3/ have copies saved as the names based in the list on worksheet 1 ("CWs") located in workbook ("Testing Samples" where the macro should live.

NOTE: both the "Template" workbook and "testing sample" workbook are in the same folder path as the destination folder "To be completed"

THE PROBLEM: When I run this VBA I keep getting an error message that says it can't find the path. and VBA run time error 1004 can't access the file.

This is a network path as well so not sure if this makes it harder

'Saves testing script template to folder "to be completed" and renames each saved template with the CW listed as its name.

```
    Sub SaveTemplateworkbookAs()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim rNames As Range, c As Range, r As Range
```

'Current file's (Samples for testing) list of names on sheet1 (CWs).

```
    Set rNames = Worksheets("CWS").Range("A2", Worksheets("CWS").Range("A2").End(xlDown))
```

'Path and name to master workbook to open for copy, saveas.

```
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path & "\Template")
    For Each c In rNames
    With wb
```

'Path and name for copied workbook
.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\To_be_completed", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, CreateBackup:=False

```
    End With
    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Next c
    wb.Close

    End Sub
```

Comment: What is the name of the template workbook (e.g. `Template.xlsx`)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.